# Does it take any reputation to see reopen requests?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

[This question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27786/what-criteria-should-be-used-in-evaluating-if-a-company-is-worth-working-for), and I understand by the comment thread that it is voted to be reopened (at the time of asking this question). However, when I look at the question, I don't see any reopen requests.

Does it take a minimal amount of reputation just to see reopen (or close) requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions says you need `3000` for casting closing/reopening votes and thus being able to see `close ()` and `reopen ()` vote counts.

This is the same amount required on all the SE sites

Comment: To append to this, any user with at least 250 reputation is able to see close and reopen counts *on their own questions*. They are also able to vote on them as well.