# Re-open closed question

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439703/how-can-i-right-the-following-in-jena) has been closed for being too vague. As a Jena developer (and committer on the Apache Jena project) I do understand what the OP is asking, although I accept that it's not phrased as clearly as it could be. It seems clear that the OP does not have English as a first language, and so I think it may be a little unfair to penalize him/her for poor phraseology by simply closing the question.

I would like the question re-opened, so that I can (i) edit it into a clearer form, and (ii) supply an answer. I propose that this would be a better way to educate the question asker about good practices at SO than simply closing the question.

Comment: You should be able to edit it right now. Are you not? If you are, let me know when you're done and I'll cast a reopen vote (it'll take 5 for it to get reopened). Alternatively, flag for moderator attention (when you're done)

Comment: I'll second that. If there is a real question in there, edit the post to let it out.

Comment: See also [Should flawed questions be closed immediately?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115603/should-flawed-questions-be-closed-immediately)

Comment: I reopened it so you can provide an answer, but I hope you'll still edit the question further to make it more clear what's being asked.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I think your edits and others made the question clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the question whether it's closed or not. At the moment, it's only comprehensible by an expert, so it's not interesting to the general public interested in Jena. If you can edit it to be more widely understood, please go ahead, then flag for reopening. The principle behind this workflow is that the question is currently close-worthy, but your edit would make it open-worthy.

Comment: Thanks, I have answered the question now. Someone else got in before me to edit the question into a more readable form.