# What problems must be solved to evolve the "Cake is Not a Lie" hat into a badge?

Tags: feature-request, edits, badge-request

Some posters don't use good spelling or grammar, or they even fail to mark up their code so that it appears at all in a question. A good edit - one which address grammar, clarity, and fixes markup - can turn a mediocre or bad question into a good and useful one.  Great edits cost a significant amount of time, and editors should be rewarded for rescuing a question.

During the recent Winter Bash, one of the [Secret Hats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012) was "Cake is Not a Lie" which was awarded for editing a post earned 5 upvotes after the edit.  It would be great to see a proper badge similar to this brought into Stack Overflow.

Here are some examples of posts which have been "saved" through editing:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/104439/revisions

(Feel free to add examples!  I apologize that I've only been able to fine my own edits thus far.)

The "Cake is Not a Lie" hat didn't have too many restrictions, and could easily be gamed. To evolve a badge out of the hat, there should probably be some additional conditions:

- Your upvote must be excluded from the number of upvotes which triggers the badge.
- The edited post must **not** be your own.
- The edit must be **substantial**, .  A certain number of characters or a complexity check (fail if " i " exists outside of code) should be passed.

What other conditions are useful to help evolve "Cake is Not a Lie" into a badge?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think there are too many challenges here to make it feasible.... if there are multiple edits, how do you know which one "saved" the question?  Would you only consider the most recent edit, or the most recent substantial edit, or would everyone who was involved in editing the question get the badge?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Fair questions!  I would defer to whatever rules were used for the "Cake is not a Lie" hat.

Comment: @KatieK: There were no rules used for it. It was *edit post* then *post receives 5 upvotes after that edit*. Very simple. It was just a hat, for fun, and didn't need complex rules, because it was just fun.

Comment: @animuson - Aha!  I did not find that question when I searched; my apologies.  I have clarified this question somewhat to focus on evolving a badge from the Cake hat.

Comment: A big difference is that the hat was *secret*, which reduced the gaming aspect. Nerds like me could otherwise edit an answer with 1000 upvotes, expecting it to soon reach 1005...

Comment: @BoPersson - Then, the badge could be awarded only on questions which started from a 0 or lower score.

Comment: What about a similar badge to promote editing/reopening? A badge for editing a closed question, getting it reopened, and having it get some upvotes. The system is quick to close questions, but editing/reopening doesn't happen too often.

Comment: @Rachel: [Give a badge to users who improve closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109543/give-a-badge-to-users-who-improve-closed-questions)